# Mac os Sierra 10.13.1 : Unable to create an account

Tags: macos, user-account

I can't create an account on mac os sierra, when I add all informations (account name, password,...), all seems to go fine, then instead of creating an account I find that a "Group" is created!

When I try to delete this group I can't

Please, Help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems odd. Can you post a screen shot of how you exactly are adding and how you know a group is created? Perhaps this isn’t what it seems at first glance.

Comment: Ok. You certainly are outside the mainstream. Is this machine bound to a central directory? Any mdm profiles?

Comment: No, in fact, I have just bought it (macbook pro used one) but it's the only device I have

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution finally, the problem was that my current user has no password set. After setting a password, everything is working!

Comment: @grgarside : why?

Comment: What are you asking ‘why’ regarding? The last sentence of your answer seemed redundant so I edited it out, that's all?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you voted down my answer